# Spatial analysis and parallel processing in R

Tags: r, point-in-polygon, parallel-processing

I am trying to do a point-in-poly analysis using R. I have 4.5 million points and 5k polygons. This is computationally intensive. I was pointed to parallel processing through another post and tried to run point.in.poly through parallel processing.

Without parallel

```
table1 = point.in.poly(spdf, all_polygons)
```

With parallel

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)


registerDoParallel(makeCluster(2))
ptm <- proc.time()
foreach(i=1:length(split_df), .combine = rbind, .packages='spatialEco','sp')  %dopar%  {
  myvars = c("LONG_X","LAT_Y")
  producers_lat_long = split_df[i][myvars]
  spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = producers_lat_long, data = split_df,
                               proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
  clip1 = point.in.poly(spdf, all_polygons)
  getValues(clip1)
}
proc.time() - ptm
endCluster()
```

Without parallel results in about 7 minute processing time for a 100k subset. With parallel takes longer, then freezes and crashed my computer. Note that I am on a four core computer.

How might I speed up this function? Without parallel processing, my rough estimation is that this process could take 6 hours.

Comment: I would try `sf::st_join(pts, pols)`. The heavy computations are done in C++ so should be acceptable re running time.

Comment: How old is your installation of r and r-spatial? As far as i know spatial indixes are pretty new to r and the sf functions. Such an index should speed this up much faster than parallel processing. Using spatial indexes this task should run in the range of seconds.

Comment: What you seem to have done there is run the whole thing `nrow` times across your CPUs. To get the win from `foreach` you have to split your task up inside the loop. For example, loop from 1:10 and then point.in.poly(spdf[a:b,], all_polygons), computing a and b from the loop index i.

Comment: @TimSalabim st_intersects could be quicker since it only returns the indexes and doesn't try and join the data frames? Note to macworthy - this is all using the new `sf` classes rather than the old `SpatialWhateverDataFrame` classes.

Comment: @Spacedman if I'm not mistaken st_join uses st_intersects by default to find the indexes and the merges the attributes using that index

Comment: @TimSalabim @Spacedman I tried `st_join` and `st_intersect`. Improvements seem marginal for the subset I'm working on.

Comment: Note that by "indexes" I mean the rows in the polygons that the point is in - not the "spatial indexes" which are data structures built to speed up point-in-polygon operations.

Comment: @Spacedman I've updated my code above to fix that (hopefully). Still having issues.

Comment: @Matte I've just updated to the most recent version of R and reinstalled packages. It doesn't appear to be speeding things up.

Comment: Make a fully reproducible example - use sample data from the R packages so we can all test this. At the moment we have no idea what `getValues` does, for example, so we can't tell where your problem is.